# Why is chmod returning 'no file or directory' while the file exists?

Tags: truenas

When setting up sonarr in truenas I get the error above.

```
iocage exec radarr mkdir /usr/local/etc/rc.d
nano /usr/local/etc/rc.d/radarr
```

then I fill in the script I need to fill in, I save.

Then I try this command
`iocage exec radarr chmod u+x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/radarr`
and get the error that the file is not found.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you ran nano without iocage?

Comment: Hmm, will need to take a look to doublecheck!